# Naive Bayes implementation: why Laplace smoothing is different from theory?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, statistics, naive-bayes-classifier

Let's have a Naive Bayes Bernoulli classifier with $n_C$ classes and $n_F$ features.

According to the formula in [here](https://derbinsky.info/public/_custom/teaching/wit-su17/comp3770/slides/lec_10_naive_bayes.pdf) and [here](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs188/sp12/slides/cs188%20lecture%2020%20--%20naive%20bayes%206PP.pdf) and almost every theory book I could see, Laplacian smoothing means that we take

$$P(x=X|c=C)=\frac{\#\{x=X,c=C\} +\alpha}{\#\{c=C\} +n_F\alpha }$$

but in the implementations of [sklearn](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/1495f6924/sklearn/naive_bayes.py#L846) and [this book](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/the-bernoulli-model-1.html) the formula is actually

$$P(x=X|c=C)=\frac{\#\{x=X,c=C\} +\alpha}{\#\{c=C\} +2\alpha}$$

why is the number of features taken as two? Is there a theoretical reason?

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is just that in the case of the Bernoulli model, your variables are binary variables which means the only values they can take are 0 or 1. Therefore the "number of features" also called "size of the vocabulary" in the case of text classification is limited to 2.